# Return false does not work in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript, I try to validate my form inside the onSubmit using javascript but it does not work, as if it will not enter my last if where I compare the size of a string. Always returns true and ends sending the form thus present input problems

```js
function validaDatos(form){
 var mensaje="";
 var solonumeros = /^([0-9])*$/
 var sololetras = /^([A-Z]|[a-z])*$/
 var doc = form.doc.value;
 var apepa = form.apepa.value;
 var apema = form.apema.value;
 var nombre = form.nombre.value;
 var telefono = form.telefono.value;
 var usuario = form.usuario.value;

 if(!solonumeros.test(doc)){
  mensaje+="Campo Documento erróneo, solo se aceptan Números";
 }
 if(!sololetras.test(apepa)){
  mensaje+="Campo Apellido Paterno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras";
 }
 if(!sololetras.test(apema)){
  mensaje+="Campo Apellido Materno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras";
 }
 if(!sololetras.test(nombre)){
  mensaje+="Campo Nombre erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras <br>";
 }
 if(!solonumeros.test(telefono)){
  mensaje+="Campo Teléfono, solo se aceptan Números ";
 }
 if(!solonumeros.test(usuario) && !sololetras.test(usuario)){
  mensaje+="Campo Usuario , Solo se Acepta Números y Letras";
 }
 alert(mensaje.length); //return > 0
    /* No compare , no return false */
 if(mensaje.length !=0){
  document.getElementByClassName('msgerror').innerHTML  = mensaje;
  return false;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form action="Models/clsUsuario.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" id="frmRegistro" onsubmit="return validaDatos(this);">
<label for="">Documento </label>
<input type="text" id="doc" name="doc" required  maxlength="11">
<label for="">Apellido P.</label>
<input type="text" id="apepa" name="apepa" required  maxlength="80">
<label for="">Apellido M.</label>
<input type="text" id="apema" name="apema" required  maxlength="80">
<label for="">Nombres </label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required  maxlength="80">
<label for="">Email : </label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
<label for="">Teléfono : </label>
<input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono"  required>
<label for="">Usuario  </label>
<input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" required>
<label for="">Clave  </label>
<input type="password" id="clave" name="clave" required>

<label for="">Dirección : </label>
<textarea name="direccion" id="direccion" required></textarea>

<input type="hidden" name="registrar" value="registrar">
<input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registro" >
<span class="msgerror"></span>
    
</form>
```

Sorry if my programming language (variables and messages) is not English.
**Before the if, I show the length of the message variable, but I should enter the if more it does not**.

[Code Run](https://repl.it/F0aF/2)

Comment: Instead of `alert(mensaje.length)` use `console.log(mensaje.length)` and look for error messages in the console (on windows, press F12 in chrome or firefox, might be different in other browsers or platforms)

Comment: In the browser console do not show errors, I thought that too but no. I will not be able to see the log because the onsubmit

Comment: Yes, it does show errors. But since you have an error in your submit-handle, the page is submitted and you don't see the error. In Chrome you can check `preserver log` and you will see that you get an error because you are trying to use a function that doesn't exists: `getElementByClassName`. There is a function called `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this part:

```
if(mensaje.length !=0){
    document.getElementByClassName('msgerror').innerHTML  = mensaje;
    return false;
}
```

There is no function called `getElementByClassName`. There is a function called [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (Notice the missing **s** in  *getElement**s**ByClassName* and that it will always return an array: It there is no elements that match, the array will be empty)

In Chrome you can check the `Preseve Log` in the developers tools to make the browser keep the logs between page loads.

The reason you don't see anything right now is that the error causes the function to abort, and since the form doesn't return false, the form will be submitted.

I also noticed that you set several different error messages by concatenating strings. That will get you into trouble if there are multiple errors, for example you could get `"Campo Documento erróneo, solo se aceptan NúmerosCampo Apellido Paterno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras"` (Notice a missing separator between `NúmerosCampo`). I suggest using an array instead, and then join it with a separator when you use it.

```
function validaDatos(form){
  var mensaje=[];

  // get the element where to set errors. It would be better to use
  // getElementById, but if you don't have an id on the element, that will
  // obviously not work. 
  var errorElement = document.getElementsByClassName("msgerror")[0];
  var solonumeros = /^([0-9])*$/
  var sololetras = /^([A-Z]|[a-z])*$/
  var doc = form.doc.value;
  var apepa = form.apepa.value;
  var apema = form.apema.value;
  var nombre = form.nombre.value;
  var telefono = form.telefono.value;
  var usuario = form.usuario.value;

  if(!solonumeros.test(doc)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Documento erróneo, solo se aceptan Números");
  }
  if(!sololetras.test(apepa)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Apellido Paterno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras");
  }
  if(!sololetras.test(apema)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Apellido Materno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras");
  }
  if(!sololetras.test(nombre)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Nombre erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras");
  }
  if(!solonumeros.test(telefono)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Teléfono, solo se aceptan Números");
  }
  if(!solonumeros.test(usuario) && !sololetras.test(usuario)){
    mensaje.push("Campo Usuario , Solo se Acepta Números y Letras");
  }
  console.log(mensaje.length); //return > 0
    /* No compare , no return false */

  // test if there is an error (the length is not null) and if the
  // errorElement exists.
  if(mensaje.length && errorElement){
    errorElement.innerHTML = mensaje.join("<br>");
  }

  // returns true if the length is 0, or false if it is any other value.
  return mensaje.length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something out of the if statement.

Try this:

```
function validaDatos(form){
var mensaje="";
var solonumeros = /^([0-9])*$/
var sololetras = /^([A-Z]|[a-z])*$/
var doc = form.doc.value;
var apepa = form.apepa.value;
var apema = form.apema.value;
var nombre = form.nombre.value;
var telefono = form.telefono.value;
var usuario = form.usuario.value;

if(!solonumeros.test(doc)){
    mensaje+="Campo Documento erróneo, solo se aceptan Números";
}
if(!sololetras.test(apepa)){
    mensaje+="Campo Apellido Paterno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras";
}
if(!sololetras.test(apema)){
    mensaje+="Campo Apellido Materno erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras";
}
if(!sololetras.test(nombre)){
    mensaje+="Campo Nombre erróneo, solo se aceptan Letras <br>";
}
if(!solonumeros.test(telefono)){
    mensaje+="Campo Teléfono, solo se aceptan Números ";
}
if(!solonumeros.test(usuario) && !sololetras.test(usuario)){
    mensaje+="Campo Usuario , Solo se Acepta Números y Letras";
}

/* No compare , no return false */
if(mensaje.length !=0){
    document.getElementByClassName('msgerror').innerHTML  = mensaje;
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried but it does not bring about positive changes. Does not validate the last if

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like that:

```
if(mensaje.length !==0){ //two equals sign
    document.getElementByClassName('msgerror').innerHTML  = mensaje;
    return false;
}
```

Also you can check if a string is empty, null or undefined use the function below:

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

To understand the difference between = vs == :

> Features of comparisons:
>
> Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
>   characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding
>   positions. 
>   Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically
>   equal (have the same number value). 
>   NaN is not equal to anything,
>   including NaN. 
>   Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
>   Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are
>   false. 
>   Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or
>   abstract comparisons. 
>   An expression comparing Objects is only true if  the operands reference the 
>   same Object.
>   Null and Undefined Types are strictly equal to themselves and abstractly equal > to each other.
>
> [Comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

*********** UPDATE *************
Try to check the lines below. Insert into the if:

```
console.log ("success") //this line
document.getElementByClassName('msgerror')[0].innerHTML  = mensaje;
```

You have to check if you have an element with this 'msgerror' class.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried but it does not bring about positive changes. Still does not compare the last if

Comment: @DarkFenix that is because you are not updating the variable mensaje! Are you?

Comment: Before the if, I show the length of the message variable, but I should enter the if more it does not.

Comment: DarkFenix the code is just fine. I am not convinced you are getting the alert box displaying more than 0

Comment: @DarkFenix just check my updated answer. You´re probably looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: Put my code online to check it out. It has tested almost everything. If I have a span with that class in my code.

Comment: @DarkFenix Please try to substitute like I did in the updated section. I included a small  detail ([0]). Your getElementByClassName was incorrect.

Comment: It is not that it does not show the message, it is that it does not even enter the if when the condition is true. I show an alert inside the if and it does not show it.